# Line width direction overlapping ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, r-sf

I have two lines with exactly the same starting/ending points. I want to show different properties based on width size, so essentially make the width start from the line and "grow" towards opposite directions.

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1, 5, 5,  5, 5, 1,1), ncol = 4, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
A[,1]
begin.coord <- data.frame(x=A[,1], y=A[,2])
end.coord   <- data.frame(x=A[,3], y=A[,4])

l_sf <- vector("list", nrow(begin.coord))
for (i in seq_along(l_sf)){
  l_sf[[i]] <- st_linestring(as.matrix(rbind(begin.coord[i, ], end.coord[i,])))
}

# Create simple feature geometry list column
l_sfc <- st_sfc(l_sf)
Lines <- st_as_sf(l_sfc)

Lines$width <- c(100,10)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = Lines, aes(size = (Lines$width)))+
  coord_sf()+
  theme_void()+
  theme()+
  labs()
```

In that the lines overlap, and I cannot find a way to make them one next to the other or have the size heading towards different directions. What would be ideal is something like the following, which is like having barplots (with different colors) for lines, but no idea how this can happen. Any help?

[image: BarplotLike]

Comment: If you mean that you would like the width of the line to vary along its length, this is not possible to do with a line segment. You must use a polygon instead (a long thin triangle or trapezoid for example)

Comment: I think @Manos C wants the line width to be entirely on one side of the line, rather than half from both sides. For example, a vertical line with a width of one has 0.5 units of width on both the left and right sides. OP wants 1 unit of width on the left side and 0 units on the right side (or vice-versa), so if two lines are overlapping, their full widths could be visible.

Comment: Thank you  @EugeneChong, exactly the point. It seems that the placement of the width is happening around the center. So my goal is not to have varying line widths along a line segment (to answer AllanCameron's comment) more to try and achieve showing both lines with different widths.